# Java http header cyrillic location

Tags: java, http, utf-8, header

I send a request with decoded Cyrillic sybols via [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). In response with status code = 301, I get the "location" field, in witch some of the path has other charset. For example:

reuqest url - `/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/hotels-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-875/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B/`

header location - `/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-875/**Ð¾ÑÐ·ÑÐ²Ñ**/`

Code:

```
Future<Response> responseFuture = client
            .prepareGet(url)
            .setBodyEncoding("UTF-8")
            .execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>() {
                @Override
                public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {
                    String location = response.getHeader("Location");
                    System.out.println(location);

                    return response;
                }

            });
```

How to get a normally encoded URL in location field?

Comment: I've added some code formatting to your URL examples and removed the "thanks".     Can you add some more info about the server?   You will probably need the cooperation of the server to encode the URL the way you expect.  Did you write the server code?  Is it some existing website?

Comment: Site http://hotels24.ua/. Server nginx+apache2+php5-fpm. Rewrite rules described in .htaccess file. Default charset - UTF-8. I have access to the server.